# Ambiguous use of 'dispatch_get_main_queue()' swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode

These two line are giving the error  **Ambiguous use of 'dispatch_get_main_queue()' swift 5** any help on how to fix it?

```
let voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
  voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = Set([PKPushTypeVoIP])
  voipRegistry.delegate = self;
}
```

#-----

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

              let alert = UIAlertView(title: "VoIP Notification", message: message, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok");
              alert.show()
          })
```

Comment: The `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_get_main_queue` Is the old Objective-C syntax (and we used back in the days of Swift 1.x). It would appear that this code is from a very old Swift project/example. We don’t use `AlertView` anymore, either. We use `AlertController` nowadays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` is not Swift. You would say `DispatchQueue.main.async`.